# Programatic selection of select does not work in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, safari

I'm using jQuery to programatically select an element in my ng-options lis. I'm using

```
$('#suggestionSelection').focus();
$('#suggestionSelection').prop('selectedIndex', -1);
```

Problem is that it works on Mozila and Chorome but doesn't work on Safari. Safari remembers the last selected element, and always just selects the next one. I tried many different ideas here on stack, but couldn't find anything.

```
<input id="questionForInput" type="text"
  ng-change="ask.getsuggestions()" autocomplete="off"
  ng-model="ask.term" class="form-control bg-dark"
  placeholder="Ask.." ng-keydown="key($event)"/>

<select id="suggestionSelection" ng-model="ask.term"
  class="suggestion-box list-group2 bg-dark" multiple="true"
  ng-keydown="key2($event)"
  ng-options="command for command in ask.suggestions">
</select>
```

Comment: Just set the `val()`: `$('#suggestionSelection').val('value')`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, this has no effect on any browser, while $('#suggestionSelection').prop('selectedIndex', -1); If I will change -1 to 0 it will start selection from second element on the list but only on Mozila and Chrome, and not Safari.

Comment: Since you are using Angular, Why do need to set using jQuery?

Comment: @Satpal, okay so I added ng-init="ask.term = options[0]" into my select and still... Also after every select, I just hide the select, I do not reset anything, but that command is launched every time the input is longer than 3 chars. So it supposed to reset itself